# SQLAlchemy group_by() summation help needed for simple linked tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've looked around for help on similar topics but could not quite find the right solution to my problem which deals with SQLAlchemy/Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Here is the situation: I have 3 tables that deal with raffle ticket data. The tables are the following: A `raffles` table:

```
class RaffleModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'raffles'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # relationship to users
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = db.relationship("UserModel", backref="raffles")

    # relationship to ticket_md
    ticket_md_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ticket_mds.id'))
    ticket_md = db.relationship("TicketMetaDataModel", backref="raffles")

    def __init__(self, user, ticket_md):
        self.user = user
        self.ticket_md = ticket_md
```

With the following sample data:

```
id    user_id    ticket_md_id
1     1          1
2     2          1
3     3          1
4     1          2
5     2          2
```

A `users` table:

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    won = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)

    # has backref via user.raffles

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, won):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.won = won
```

With the following sample data:

```
id    first_name    last_name    won
1     Rob           Stark        False
2     Stan          Clark        False
3     Tom           Dark         False
```

And lastly a `ticket_mds` table:

```
class TicketMetaDataModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ticket_mds'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    raffle_type = db.Column(db.String(20))
    description = db.Column(db.String(200))
    modifier = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # has backref via ticket_md.raffles

    def __init__(self, raffle_type, description, modifier):
        self.raffle_type = raffle_type
        self.description = description
        self.modifier = modifier
```

With the following sample data:

```
id    raffle_type    description    modifier
1     type_1         blah blah      21
2     type_2         blah blah      5
```

My issue here lies in the fact that I can't seem to quite figure out a query to get the sum of ticket points (based on the `TicketMetaDataModel.modifier` attribute) grouped by the user from the raffles table to return results in the following format:

`first_name`, `last_name`, `total_points`,
e.g.:

```
Rob    Stark    26
Stan   Clark    26
Tom    Dark     21
```

I have tried the following (but have not been able to get further from there):

```
query = db.session.query(RaffleModel.id, UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name, TicketMetaDataModel.modifier)
query = query.join(UserModel).join(TicketMetaDataModel)
results = query.all()
results equals:

[(1, 'Rob', 'Stark', 21), (2, 'Stan', 'Clark', 21), (3, 'Tom', 'Dark', 21),(4, 'Rob', 'Stark', 5), (5, 'Stan', 'Clark', 5)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got me intrigued and I did a self contained example

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

from pprint import pformat as pf

Base = declarative_base()

class ReprMixin(object):

    """A mixin to implement a generic __repr__ method"""

    def as_dict(self):
        """return instance as a dictionary"""
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s(%s)>' % (self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join([f'{c.name} = {getattr(self, c.name)}' for c in self.__table__.columns]))

class RaffleModel(ReprMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'raffles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # relationship to users
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship("UserModel", backref="raffles")

    # relationship to ticket_md
    ticket_md_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ticket_mds.id'))
    ticket_md = relationship("TicketMetaDataModel", backref="raffles")

    def __init__(self, user, ticket_md):
        self.user = user    
        self.ticket_md = ticket_md

    @classmethod
    def insert_defaults(cls, session):
        for user_id, ticket_id in zip([1,2,3,1,2],[1,1,1,2,2]):
            user = session.query(UserModel).filter_by(id=user_id).scalar()
            ticket = session.query(TicketMetaDataModel).filter_by(id=ticket_id).scalar()
            session.add(cls(user, ticket))
        session.commit()


class UserModel(ReprMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(25))
    last_name = Column(String(25))
    won = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)

    # has backref via user.raffles

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, won):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.won = won

    @classmethod
    def insert_defaults(cls, session):
        for first_name, last_name, won in zip("Rob Stan Tom".split(),"Stark Clark Dark".split(), [False]*3):
            session.add(cls(first_name, last_name, won))
        session.commit()


class TicketMetaDataModel(ReprMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ticket_mds'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    raffle_type = Column(String(20))
    description = Column(String(200))
    modifier = Column(Integer)

    # has backref via ticket_md.raffles

    def __init__(self, raffle_type, description, modifier):
        self.raffle_type = raffle_type
        self.description = description
        self.modifier = modifier

    @classmethod
    def insert_defaults(cls, session):
        for raffle_type, description, modifier in zip("type1 type2".split(), "desc1 desc2".split(), [21,5]):
            session.add(cls(raffle_type, description, modifier))
        session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    from pprint import pprint as pp
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Session = sessionmaker()

    sess = Session(bind=engine)

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    TicketMetaDataModel.insert_defaults(sess)
    UserModel.insert_defaults(sess)
    RaffleModel.insert_defaults(sess)


    print('************************')
    pp(sess.query(UserModel).all())
    print('************************')
    pp(sess.query(RaffleModel).all())
    print('************************')
    pp(sess.query(TicketMetaDataModel).all())


    from sqlalchemy import func
    query = sess.query(UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name, func.sum(TicketMetaDataModel.modifier))

    query2 = query.join(RaffleModel.user)\
                .join(RaffleModel.ticket_md)\
                .group_by(UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name)

    print('************************')
    print(query)
    print(query.all())
    print('************************')
    print(query2.all())
    print(query2)

    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

running it it returns

```
************************
[<UserModel(id = 1, first_name = Rob, last_name = Stark, won = False)>,
 <UserModel(id = 2, first_name = Stan, last_name = Clark, won = False)>,
 <UserModel(id = 3, first_name = Tom, last_name = Dark, won = False)>]
************************
[<RaffleModel(id = 1, user_id = 1, ticket_md_id = 1)>,
 <RaffleModel(id = 2, user_id = 2, ticket_md_id = 1)>,
 <RaffleModel(id = 3, user_id = 3, ticket_md_id = 1)>,
 <RaffleModel(id = 4, user_id = 1, ticket_md_id = 2)>,
 <RaffleModel(id = 5, user_id = 2, ticket_md_id = 2)>]
************************
[<TicketMetaDataModel(id = 1, raffle_type = type1, description = desc1, modifier = 21)>,
 <TicketMetaDataModel(id = 2, raffle_type = type2, description = desc2, modifier = 5)>]
************************
SELECT users.first_name AS users_first_name, users.last_name AS users_last_name, sum(ticket_mds.modifier) AS sum_1 
FROM users, ticket_mds
[('Tom', 'Dark', 78)]
************************
[('Rob', 'Stark', 26), ('Stan', 'Clark', 26), ('Tom', 'Dark', 21)]
SELECT users.first_name AS users_first_name, users.last_name AS users_last_name, sum(ticket_mds.modifier) AS sum_1 
FROM raffles JOIN users ON users.id = raffles.user_id JOIN ticket_mds ON ticket_mds.id = raffles.ticket_md_id GROUP BY users.first_name, users.last_name
```

It seems that your model would benefit greatly if `RaffleModel` were an association table for a many to many relationship between `UserModel` and `TicketMetadataModel`

Comment: Thank you for your response too! by pass query aggregator to your query do you mean doing the following `query = query(query_aggregator)`? because if so that throws me the following error: `TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable`

Comment: hmmm that has given me result =  `[(1, 'Rob', 'Stark', 21, 21), (2, 'Stan', 'Clark', 21, 21), (3, 'Tom', 'Dark', 21, 21), (4, 'Rob', '
Stark', 5, 5), (5, 'Stan', 'Clark', 5, 5)]` which isn't quite what I'm looking for as I already have that. what I'm going for is: `[('Rob', 'Stark', 26), ('Stan', 'Clark', 26), ('Tom', 'Dark', 21)]`

Comment: Yes I posted it up in my previous comment. I get `[(1, 'Rob', 'Stark', 21, 21), (2, 'Stan', 'Clark', 21, 21), (3, 'Tom', 'Dark', 21, 21), (4, 'Rob', ' Stark', 5, 5), (5, 'Stan', 'Clark', 5, 5)]`

Comment: I meant not `print(query.all())` but `print(query)` only. It should return the query in SQL language

Comment: This is what it returns: `SELECT raffles.id AS raffles_id, users.first_name AS users_first_name, users.last_name AS users_last
_name, ticket_mds.modifier AS ticket_mds_modifier, sum(ticket_mds.modifier) AS raffle_sum
FROM raffles JOIN users ON users.id = raffles.user_id JOIN ticket_mds ON ticket_mds.id = raffles.tic
ket_md_id GROUP BY raffles.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, ticket_mds.modifier`

Comment: I've updated my answer, as I had a typo in the defaults for `RaffleModel`

Comment: Thank you thank you! Sorry for delayed response, but yes your query finally solved my issue. And yeah I do now fully realize that a many-to-many table between `TicketMetaDataModel` and `UserModel` would have been much better and intuitive. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right. You are trying to group by the values which you have already got through a join.

```
from sqlalchemy import func
query = db.session.query(UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name, func.sum(TicketMetaDataModel.modifier))
query = query.join(RaffleModel,RaffleModel.user_id==UserModel.id).join(RaffleModel.ticket_md_id==TicketMetaDataModel.id)
.group_by(UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name)
```

It should give you the required result

Comment: Thank you for the response! for some strange reason that gives me the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'sum' and 'ticket_mds' ` Also, kind of new to SQL in general, so I'm wondering what the reason is for including that join at the end?

Comment: It is looking for foreign key relationship but we can tell Sqlalchemy parameters on which it should join. What do you mean by join at the end? PS: I have updated the code snippet

Comment: Oh I now see that you are rewritting my query from the beginning but including the summation in it. Thank you! I think there is a missing parathesis there are somewhere because when I try `query = db.session.query((UserModel.first_name,UserModel.last_name,func.sum(TicketMetaDataMod
modifier).join(TicketMetaDataModel,TicketMetaDataModel.id=UserModel.ticket_md_id).group_by(UserMo
.first_name,UserModel.last_name)` it thinks I am continuing onto the next line and giving me a  `...`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.I have included missing ')' for query object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, again, I tried `query = db.session.query(UserModel.first_name,UserModel.last_name,func.sum(TicketMetaDataModel.modifier)).join(TicketMetaDataModel,TicketMetaDataModel.id=UserModel.ticket_md_id).group_by(UserModel
.first_name,UserModel.last_name)` but now I end up with the error `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`. After some searching around is there some wrong sequence in the ordering when you were joining?

Comment: I am so sorry I cannot test in my local. Actually it should be`==` in join statement rather than expression of `=`. That is the nature of how SqlAlachemy works.

Comment: ahhh yes, and now final (hopefully) thing, i am thrown the error `AttributeError: type object 'UserModel' has no attribute 'ticket_md_id'` in the join. Since I am unfamiliar with joins, am I to try to join on some other attribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171342/discussion-between-mad-and-dgav).